# Yii2 insert date and time in sql

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am creating a yii application and I want to insert data into the database but the problem is how to insert date and time. It fails to insert every detail until I remove the date time column from the database .

This is the controller class:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use amnah\yii2\user\models\User;
use app\models\Influence;
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use amnah\yii2\user\controllers\DefaultController as SuperDefault;

class DefaultController extends SuperDefault {

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index', 'confirm', 'resend', 'logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?', '@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['account', 'profile','contact', 'resend-change', 'cancel','advertiser_dashboard','influencer_dashboard', 'influenza_info', 'advertiser'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'register','contact','influencer_dashboard', 'advertiser_dashboard','register_advert','forgot', 'reset', 'login-email', 'login-callback'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post', 'get'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }


    public function actionInfluenza_info()
    {
        $u_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $user = User::findOne($u_id);
           $influence= new Influence(); 

        if ($influence->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

                    $influence_data = Yii::$app->request->post('Influence', []);
                 $influence->firstname = $influence_data['firstname'];
                 $influence->lastname = $influence_data['lastname'];
                 $influence->email = $influence_data['email'];
                 $influence->city = $influence_data['city'];
                 $influence->type = $influence_data['type'];
                 $influence->pic = $influence_data['pic'];
                 $influence->address = $influence_data['address'];
                 $influence->country = $influence_data['country'];
                 $influence->gender = $influence_data['gender'];
                   $influence->id = $u_id;

                  $influence->save();

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash("Profile-success", Yii::t("user", "Profile updated"));
            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('influenza_info', [
                 'user' => $user,

                  'influence' =>$influence
            ]);
        }

    }

    }
```

this is the model class

```
  <?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\controllers\Expression;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "influence".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $firstname
 * @property string $lastname
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $type
 * @property string $pic
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $country
 * @property string $gender
 */
class Influence extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'influence';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'user_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'city', 'type', 'pic', 'address', 'country', 'gender'], 'required'],
            [['id', 'user_id'], 'integer'],
       [['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'city', 'type', 'pic', 'address', 'country', 'gender'], 'string', 'max' => 30]
        ];
    }
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
if ($this->isNewRecord) { // new record only, otherwise time is inserted every time this record is updated
    $this->created_at = new Expression('NOW()');
}
parent::afterSave($insert);
}
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'firstname' => 'Firstname',
            'lastname' => 'Lastname',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'city' => 'City',
            'type' => 'Type',
            'pic' => 'Pic',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'country' => 'Country',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'created_at' => 'Created_at',
        ];
    }
}
```

the table sql

```
CREATE TABLE `influence` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ;
```

how do i make it insert automatically. if i try it from my admin it works and gets the dateand time . but with yii it does not.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I remove the created attribute from the required rule.
I then create a beforeSave() method and on a new record insert it with Expression.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
if ($this->isNewRecord) { // new record only, otherwise time is inserted every time this record is updated
    $this->created = new Expression('NOW()');
}
parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Make sure you import Expression into the model

**Update**
updated code thanks @crafter

Comment: not error nothing is inserting unless i delete the time colomn in the database i edited my model class in the question see how it is not did i do it well

Comment: try this: `if(!model->save()) print_r($model->getErrors())` That will tell you which rule is failing

Comment: updated code, try that, but include the `if(!model->save()) print_r($model->getErrors())` to see what if anything is failing

Answer (score 2):

you should use the Expression in the following way. Refer this link [Class yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html)

When an Expression object is embedded within a SQL statement or fragment, it will be replaced with the $expression property value without any DB escaping or quoting. For example,

```
$expression = new Expression('NOW()');
$now = (new \yii\db\Query)->select($expression)->scalar();  // SELECT NOW();
echo $now; // prints the current date
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 `created` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

in you db table but seems you have model field created as a string.

```
* @property string $created
```

check if there is mismatch problem related to ths field and eventually provide the right conversion before save or change the model (or the db) in order to have the same data type ..

Anyway you don't have rules for $created and the is not POSTED 
add

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'user_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'city', 'type', 'pic', 'address', 'country', 'gender'], 'required'],
        [['id', 'user_id'], 'integer'],
   [['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'city', 'type', 'pic', 'address', 'country', 'gender'], 'string', 'max' => 30]
   [['created',], 'safe'],

    ];
}
```

Try also

```
 $influence->save(false);
```

in this way you save the data withot validation check (use this  only for debugging) if in this way the model is saved the  try addding

```
       [['created'], 'date'],
```

in rules

Comment: There is not date data type in PHP. (Human readable) Dates will exist as strings in PHP.

Comment: I this the probem is related to the fact you don't have a rule or a safe declaration in model rules.  I have update the answer

Comment: I have update the answer .  try save(false) and tr adding  [['created'], 'date'], to the rules

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are confusing the beforeSave and afterSave events.

In addition, your field name is created, not created at.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord) { // new record only, otherwise time is inserted every time this record is updated
        $this->created = new Expression('NOW()');  // <== You were setting $this->created_at
    }
    parent::beforeSave($insert);  // <== You were calling afterSave()
}
```